# Complex Decode statement

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

```
decode(
    atc_bdm.roleinterritory2,
    NULL, 
    DECODE(
        atc_nam.roleinterritory2, 
        NULL, 
        atc_gbdm.name, 
        atc_nam.name
    ), 
    atc_bdm.name
) territory_user
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with oracle, NVL2 would be nice to see it.

> NVL2( 'column', 'when is not null', 'when is null' )

```
NVL2(
    atc_bdm.roleinterritory2,
    atc_bdm.name, 
    NVL2(atc_nam.roleinterritory2, atc_nam.name, atc_gbdm.name)    
) territory_user
```